# Having Active Directory password length of more than 8 characters when that password is used to access mainframe systems

Tags: active-directory

I am an intern with a Credit Union. I was surprised to find out that my Active Directory password length cannot be more than 8 characters. They use RACF for access to TSO or OMVS. I asked my mentor and he told me AD passwords are used to access the mainframe so this limitation of not more than 8 characters for password length.

1. Is there any way to address this with the current version of RACF?
2. Is that unavoidable if you need direct access to TSO or OMVS?
3. Is there any workaround for this? I know RACF has passphrases which was advised by their IT team but heard the credit union staff was not interested in it.
4. Mainframes are common at large banks. How do large banks have a password longer than 8 characters?

This is my second week as an intern but it sounds like the AD password is used to authenticate to lot of back-end systems which apparently are mainframe.

Saw this [Why do some bank websites use passwords that are not case sensitive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86249/why-do-some-bank-websites-use-passwords-that-are-not-case-sensitive/86252#86252) and it sounds like my credit union.